# Create single image ofmultiple video frames using FFMPEG

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I would like to create an image from a couple of frames in a video, i.e. either create multiple images and blend them or create an image from multiple frames. I have been using FFMPEG to get a single frame image using the code below but cannot find a way to blend a couple of these images and save as a single image or make FFMPEG create the image from multiple frames.

```
-ss 00:05:40 -i video.AVI -vframes 1 -vf image.jpg'
```

Comment: google + "ffmpeg mosaic from frames" =  http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20take%20multiple%20screenshots%20to%20an%20image%20(tile,%20mosaic)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't want to create a tile or mosaic but actually blend the images into one. Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: What does "blend" mean? Can you provide an example image?

Comment: I cannot add it to the post yet because my reputation is not high enough but you can see a link to a blended image of a fish in a tank with sandy substrate here http://i.stack.imgur.com/dpHdJ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using ImageMagick - it is free and available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org). It has C, C++, Perl and PHP bindings and can be used from the command line.

Depending on how you wish to merge your images, you could use one of these:

```
convert -evaluate-sequence mean a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg d.jpg
```

which takes 3 images (a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg), which I artificially added noise to, and then averages them to create d.jpg which you can see is less noisy. Or maybe you prefer to take the median of the pixels at each point:

```
convert -evaluate-sequence median a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg d.jpg
```

Or you could use:

```
composite -blend 30 foreground.jpg background.jpg blended.jpg
```

for a 30% blend.

**EDITED**

If your fish are dark in the image and you want to remove them, you can just choose the lighter of the two pixels in your images at every point like this:

```
convert a.jpg b.jpg -compose lighten -composite result.jpg
```

[image: a.jpg]
[image: d.jpg]

Comment: thanks that sounds like a potential good option. I have been trying to get it to work on windows with command prompt but there is barely any information to help me set it up and most is focused on php. I try to run your line of code but it doesn't work. How does it know what directory it works in? Even if I specify the right directory it doesnt work..

Comment: Try using the portable, statically linked, no-install version of ImageMagick (I think it is listed last) and then specify the full path when you run it because Windows has another utility called "convert" which converts NTFS filesystems and the name clashes.

Comment: Thanks that actually did the trick. I spent about 4 hours on trying ImageMagick to work today.. thanks!

Comment: Actually, I now manage to get a blended image (see here http://i.stack.imgur.com/VSTzZ.png), but is there a way to create a picture that contains most pixels that are the same between all images? Such that instead of it showing the fish in each individual picture it doesnt show the fish at all as the sand in most of the other images stays the same except for the image showing the fish (I hope that is clear), i.e. between the three that would be only showing the sand

Comment: I think you will get a better response if you edit your question, and say how many input images you have, and give links to 2-3 input images and also some indication of how you want the processed image to look...

Comment: Maybe you can tell us how you created your blended image - did you use Photoshop, if so, which blending mode did you use?

Comment: I have updated my answer to try and assist further - else you will need to answer my questions above please.

Comment: Pleasure! I love it when a plan comes together :-)